# Azure.Storage.Queues: calling QueueClient.SendMessageAsync in parallel

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core

Would it make any benefit if I call QueueClient.SendMessageAsync (Azure.Storage.Queues) in parallel?
At the moment I call it like that:

```
        var client = new QueueClient(
            Options.CurrentValue.ConnectionString,
            Options.CurrentValue.ItemRecalculateQueueName);

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var message = CreateItemRecalculationMessage(item);

            try
            {
                await client.SendMessageAsync(message, ct);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.Error(e, "Failed to recalculate item {item}", item);
            }
        }
```

If so, is there any limit of reasonable parallelization?
At the moment messages are added in a sequential fashion.

Thanks, Radek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would it make any benefit if I call QueueClient.SendMessageAsync
> (Azure.Storage.Queues) in parallel?

Most certainly. You will definitely benefit from sending messages in parallel using something like [`Task.WaitAll()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall?view=net-5.0) as you will be able to send more messages in the same amount of time.

> If so, is there any limit of reasonable parallelization?

In my experience, limiting the maximum number of parallel tasks to the number of virtual CPUs gives the best results. I believe this has something to do with context switching at the CPU level.